# Integrating asyncronous twisted code into synchronous python code

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, twisted

How can I have a synchronous code that contains an asynchronous code section implemented by Twisted? That code section also needs to be called several times which interferes with reactor.run() eventloop.
What I want to implement is Half-Sync/Half-Async pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of options for this.  Probably you just want [Crochet](https://crochet.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.0/), but LVH gave [a PyCon talk on mixing Twisted together with various other systems](http://www.pyvideo.org/video/2597/twisted-mixing), including both other async frameworks and "plain" synchronous Python code; you might want to watch that to see what your options are.